# Download com Sockets

Tags: socket, lua

Estou usando o [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html) e queria fazer download de arquivos com ele, mas não sei como, consegui baixar arquivo de texto assim:

```
local file = io.open("Blabla.txt", "w")
file:write(tostring(http.request("Http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/News.txt")))
file:close()
io.write("Downloaded!\n")
io.read()
```

Como poderia baixar arquivos de outros formatos?(Exe, rar...)

@Edit:
Tentei:

```
arq = http.request("http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/1.7z")
for ind, val in pairs(arq) do
print(ind)
end
```

Retornou: `Table expected, got string.`. Mas quando eu tento o write, continua a não funcionar.

Comment: Você tentou e não conseguiu? Qual o problema. Nunca usei LuaSocket mas em tese é para ela conseguir baixar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Tente, ele "baixou" o arquivo, só que corrompido.
Tentei esse arquivo: http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/1.7z

Comment: Eu não estou com Lua aqui para testar. Talvez seu problema esteja na gravação. De qualquer forma desta forma não compila. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Você leu a documentação, provavelmente vem um cabeçalho HTTP antes do arquivo, você precisaria separar esta parte. Confira o conteúdo dos arquivos que você baixou se tem o *header*.

Comment: Edite na pergunta o que tentei.

Comment: Esse segundo código não parece fazer o menor sentido pra mim. De qq forma, já dei a dica do que pode ser o problema.

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer na sua explicação '-'

Comment: Você consegue colocar aqui as primeiras linhas do arquivo `Blabla.txt`?

Comment: Não tem nada além do conteúdo arquivo. -> 30/10/2014 <-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não estava conseguindo pois estava abrindo um arquivo binário no modo texto.
Quando mudei "w"(write) para "wb"(write binary), consegui. Ficou assim:

```
local file = io.open("1.7z", "wb")
file:write(tostring(http.request("Http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/1.7z")))
file:close()
io.write("Downloaded!\n")
io.read()
```

Exatamente o que o Maniero disse.